# AP Calculus AB Free Response Question

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I tried solving the problems below but I got confused with question c and I have no idea how to solve. I have my solution for questions a,b and d but not sure if my solutions are right.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: For the b part, the answer is $f'(g(3x)) \cdot g'(3x) \cdot 3$. For the c part, the tangent to a curve at point $(x, g(x))$  is a line passing through that point with slope $g'(x)$. Does that help?

Comment: @sudeep5221 I was able to solve c but not sure if my answer is right. For b, you're right. I forgot to take the derivative of the inside. how about my d? is it right?

Comment: For c part, the slope is $g'(1) = -2$. Thus the answer is $y - 2 = -2(x - 1)$. For the d part, the equation should be $f'(x) + 3 (g(x))^2 g'(x) = y + x \frac{dy}{dx}$.  Not sure why you multiplied $dy/dx$ with derivative of $(g(x))^3$, the rest of it was correct it seems. As an aside, I feel the question of part d itself is incorrect. If you verify, $(1,4)$ does not lie on that curve.